# Packaging Multiple UWP applications into 1 container with Microsoft Store

Tags: windows, uwp, packaging, winui-3

I'd like to bundle multiple launchable UWP apps into 1 single container for sharing the local data.

We can think it of as

- App 1
- App 2

which will share the same LocalState folder, but they will have their own application registry and they'll be able to be launched individually.

Things I've thought about to make it happen:

- There is [**Applications** schema](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/schemas/appxpackage/uapmanifestschema/element-applications) but I don't think Microsoft Store allows packages that has 2 separate apps.
- There is [**Optional package**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/msix/package/optional-packages) approach, but this is mainly for splitting the app into smaller pieces and Optional Package can't be a separate executable from the main package.
- There is [**App Extensions**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/how-to-create-an-extension) approach, which I think can serve as a shared state for multiple separate applications, but it'll be really hard to manage large amount of state (like a database) between two apps + it's not really designed for this purpose.

Switching to WinAppSDK for making an application bundle and side loading is **not** an option for me.

Is there any other way to make it happen other than the provided approaches above?

Comment: Did my reply help you?

Comment: Unfortunately no. In the end somebody else suggested the use of PublisherCacheFolders capability. I can share data between two applications via publisher cache folder since I am the publisher of both applications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like only way to achieve shared data between two apps is to have them use [publisherCacheFolders](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.applicationdata.getpublishercachefolder?view=winrt-22621)

If you own both applications they can share data using specified folders in the manifest.

Also one note, this extension must be defined under "Package" tag instead of "Application" in the manifest. Otherwise you'll get invalid schema errors during AppxManifest generation and your builds won't complete.

Answer (score 0):

The information you collected in your question is complete. If the side loading is not in your consideration range, then there is really no other way available at the moment.